# How to Run a command on all subfolders

Tags: shell, files, wildcards

If you have a series of sub folders (like from `a` to `z`) and want to run a command on each one of them (like `dsmmigrate * &` ) how do you do that? The manual approach would be,

```
cd a 
dsmmigrate * &
cd ../b
```

That seems too complicated, so I believe there must be an easier approach.

Comment: `find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 echo do somthing`

Answer (score 5):

Yes, changing the working directory back and forth is cumbersome and not really what you would like to do as it can lead to extremely weird situations in more complex scripts, unless you are careful.

The usual method for changing the working directory for a simple command is to put the `cd` and to invocation of the command in a sub-shell. The working directory will be changed for the sub-shell but the change is not carried over to the rest of the script as the sub-shell is executing in its own environment.

Example: Executing `mycommand` inside all directories in the current working directory:

```
for d in *; do
  if [ -d "$d" ]; then         # or:  if test -d "$d"; then
    ( cd "$d" && mycommand )
  fi
done
```

or in your case, with known directories `a` and `b`:

```
for d in a b; do
  ( cd "$d" && dsmmigrate * & )
done
```

I don't know the `dsmmigrate` tool, so I can't say whether running it this way is right or not.

**EDIT:** It turns out that the [`dsmmigrate` tool](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSR2R_6.4.0/com.ibm.itsm.hsmul.doc/r_cmd_dsmmigrate.html) has a `-Recursive` flag:

```
$ dsmmigrate -Recursive /path
```

Comment: Let say I can't place the script in the root directory but I want the command to apply to all the folders in the root directory, do I just add a cd "root directory"? In the shel code above ? Above the shell code ? Thanks

Comment: @SuperKing No, it is likely that you can't place the script in the root directory, and you don't need to either. If you want to do this for all folders in the root directory (and you know that this is the right thing to do), then take the one of my example loops (the first one will run folder by folder) and change the frst line to `for d in /*; do`.

Comment: getting an error , syntax error at line 5; 'do


for d in path/*; do
  if [ -d "$d" ]; then         # or:  if test -d "$d"; then
    ( cd "$d" && dsmmigrate * & )
  fi
done
done

Comment: @SuperKing The `do` at the start shouldn't be there. Look at what I wrote. And there's an extra `done` at the end...

Comment: for d in path/*; do
  if [ -d "$d" ]; then      
    ( cd "$d" dsmmigrate * &  )
  fi
done
done

Comment: ' unexpectedh: syntax error at line 2 : `

Comment: still having the unexpected syntax error at line 2

Comment: @SuperKing Why do you still have two `done` at the end? If you remove that and make sure there are newlines after `do`, `then`, `)`, and `fi`, it ought to be correct.  I just checked it with [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: I only had one done, not sure why its showing 2 when I pasted. I think the issue is the format window format to unix ASCII

Comment: Works beautifully, however new small issue. in path/* only apply the command in the sub folders but it does not apply command to the folders within the subfolders

Comment: @SuperKing That wasn't part of the original question, but I'll add it to the answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @SuperKing I [looked up](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSR2R_6.4.0/com.ibm.itsm.hsmul.doc/r_cmd_dsmmigrate.html) that `dsmmigrate` thing, and it has a `-Recursive` flag. Can't you use that on `/path` directly?

Comment: Not really sure how to do that, I'm a complete unix noob

Comment: @SuperKing Ok, so I don't know what the command does, but according to [its manual](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSR2R_6.4.0/com.ibm.itsm.hsmul.doc/r_cmd_dsmmigrate.html), you should be able to run it as `dsmmigrate -Recursive /path`.

Comment: See also `for d in */` to avoid the `[ -d "$d" ]`.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas , what do you mean?

Comment: @SuperKing, I mean that `for d in */` will  loop on directories (and symlinks to directories) only, so then you don't need to test `[ -d "$d" ]`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following, when your current directory is `parent_directory`:

```
for d in [a-z]
do
    ( cd $d && your-command-here )
done
```

The `(` and `)` create a subshell, so the current directory isn't changed in the main script.

Comment: did any of answer helped you ? If yes, then please consider accepting answer by clicking on right mark below up/down arrow button.

Answer (score 2):

This is my way of submitting several jobs in the subfolders :

```
for d in */; do ( cd "$d" && yourcommand ) ; done
```